# Are there any undergraduate research/internship opportunities in math/science education/history?

Tags: mathematics, teaching, science, academic-history, philosophy

(Apologies if this isn't the right place for such a post. I see lots of advice for undergraduates hoping to pursue research in math and science, but haven't come across anything for the "soft" stuff like their history and pedagogy.)

I'm an undergrad math student (will have one more term left after the summer) and I'm hoping to get some advice on summer plans. While I really like math, and I'm considering grad school, I've always been really interested in science education, science in pop culture, and the history of science. I love the book *A Short History of Nearly Everything* and Youtube channels like Vsauce. Working as a science writer or museum curator would probably be a dream job for me. I'm hoping to do something in that realm in the future.

Does anyone know of any good ways to get involved in this sort of thing? It seems like people in this arena come from a pretty wide range of backgrounds. When I think about the parts of math and science that I really like, I keep coming back to the historical, cultural, philosophical, and pedagogical aspects, so something along those lines would be awesome.

I'm living in Canada right now, but I'd love to travel so I'm open to any location. I also have good grades (just under 4.0), if that matters for anything. That said, I'm really open to anything, academia or otherwise.

~~~

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to look at the [The Canadian Society for History
and Philosophy of Mathematics](http://www.cshpm.org/) web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Find some people doing your dream job.  Write to them and request an opportunity to do a shadow as part of your career exploration process.  Include a copy of your unofficial transcript and CV.  Make it clear that you would be grateful for any advice they may have about where to study, and any additional degree, coursework or job experience that would help you achieve your goal, but make the advice part optional.  Let them know how to contact you if they would find phone easier than email.

Please also consider applying for science *outreach* jobs.  These might be available at a research institute that is part of a large university.

Sometimes people create such a job organically, starting by doing this and that while employed doing something else (possibly related).  For example, enrichment classes taught after school at elementary schools.  Being a community advisor for a science club at a middle or high school.